# Find $\{\bar{u}_{k}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ s.t. $\{\|\bar{u}_{k}\|\}$ is bounded increasing but $\{\bar{u}_{k}\}$ not convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out how a sequence's distance can be increasing and bounded? Would the sequence $\{(-1)^n)\}$ satisfy this?

> Find a sequence $\{\bar{u}_{k}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the property that $\{\|\bar{u}_{k}\|\}$ is a bounded increasing sequence but with $\{\bar{u}_{k}\}$ not convergent.

Comment: How does $(-1)^n$ belong to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  For future reference, please see the [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting symbols on this site, as well as [how to choose a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) and in general [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Give it a bit of thought. Your instinct is spot on, just need to move it into two dimensions as @josé-carlos-santos points out.

Comment: Would writing it as <(-1)^n,1> move it into two dimensions and satisfy this?

Comment: No, that's still a real sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a spiral from inside a unite disk which gets closed and closer to the unit circle from inside but never crosses it. Pick $u_{k}$ on this spiral.